# $H^1(\Omega')$ is in general not a subspace of $H^1 (\Omega)$ for bounded domains $\Omega' \subset \Omega$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Reading about Sobolev spaces I found the following statement:

$H^1 ({\Omega}')$ is not a subspace of $H^1(\Omega)$ for $\Omega'\subset \Omega$.

$\left(\text{However } \ H^1_0 (\Omega ')\subset H^1_0(\Omega)\right)$

I guess that the reason behind is that you can not control $f\in H^1(\Omega ')$ outside $\Omega'$. But I'm having a hard time thinking a counterexample or a more rigorous explanation.

Comment: can't you take something that blows up at the boundary?

Comment: First of all, a function on $\Omega'$ is not a function on $\Omega$, so one has to say something to make sense of the inclusion in the first place. This is also the case (although easy) for $H^1_0 (\Omega ')\subset H^1_0(\Omega)$. Please say something.